# Remove multiple lines from xml

Tags: xml, lines

Lets say I have got such xml structure:

```
<list>
    <main id="1" name="asd1">
        <reward id="5">
            <set reward_id="32" value="5123" />
            <set reward_id="352" value="12" />
        </reward>
        <reward id="6">
            <set reward_id="72" value="666666" />
            <set reward_id="32" value="21" />
        </reward>
    </main>
</list>
```

and I have got 30 files like this with a lot more lines. My problem is, that I want to delete EVERY line from EVERY file where reward_id is "32". Doing this one-by-one would take weeks. Do you know any program that can handle my problem?

Edit: value is changed in every line, also sometimes there are more attributes than just those two.

Comment: Are you a programmer? then you could whip something up for example with command line and save as BAT file.

Comment: I am just programming a bit in Java, creating code that would remove those lines would take time for me :/

Comment: Ahh, too bad.Unofrtunately I'm not aware of any out-of-the-box free tools that do what you want it to do.

Comment: If you know in advance what values they can all have, you can do a "find and replace". But do you know in advance all possible values for reward_id="32" ?

Comment: no, there are like infinity possible values so probably i will have to create the tool in java or just while those XML files are loading to my program, skip lines where reward_id is 32 and leave files as they are :)

Answer (score 1):

The deletion from a single xml file can be done easily by this xsl transform:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="set[@reward_id='32']" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This transform contains two templates.  The first is an identity transform which simply copies everything.  The second defines an exception for the data you want to skip.  This sort of thing is pretty common in xslt.

In order to apply this to a file, you need to use a tool for applying xsl.  What I use to do this from the command line is xsltproc, which may already be on your system if you're using MacOS or Linux.  If not [this page](http://www.sagehill.net/docbookxsl/InstallingAProcessor.html) will help you get it.

When I wrote the above transform, I named it test.xsl and applied it to your sample xml saved as test.xml.  Running it by

```
xsltproc test.xsl test.xml > testout.xml
```

produced a file testout.xml containing:

```
<list>
    <main id="1" name="asd1">
        <reward id="5">

            <set reward_id="352" value="12"/>
        </reward>
        <reward id="6">
            <set reward_id="72" value="666666"/>

        </reward>
    </main>
</list>
```

To apply this to a set of files, you could create a shell script to go through the files and for each apply a command similar to this but of course with the filenames varying.

Answer (score 0):

Any **good text editor** could do the trick using *xml plugins, search and replace, and regexes*. Choose one, and master it. The programming gods will reward you handsomely!

My weapon of choice is currently **[Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/)**.

As an alternative, you could use command-line utilities and shells, for example *PowerShell*. The learning curve is a bit steeper, but it would bring its own advantages as well.

Comment: find and replace won't work if the lines are somewhat dynamic. You can replace the static part, but you want to replace the whole line with an empty string, so also the dynamic part.